# Disk image in read-only with persistent storage image

Tags: storage, persistence, usb-drive, disk-image, mass-storage

so i already know how to create and mount disk images

but here is the example idea of what im looking for

create a image (ext4) as DiskA.img,
mount it, fill it with data,
remount read-only

`i would like to`

create a image (ext4) for persistent storage as DiskB.img,
and on remount of DiskA.img to read-only,

have DiskB.img be somehow used for the changes,

so the pair would have to be used for the "storage container"

`just looking for all the different methods to do this`

we have this with the pen drives, but, how can we do this with basic disk images

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? You want a persistent live system, where the booted live system is in one drive and the partition for persistence is located in another drive. This is very easy to create. 1. In a persistent live drive, remove or rename the casper-rw partition or file; 2. In the other drive, create an ext2, ext3 or ext4 file system and put the label `casper-rw` onto it. Reboot and there you are :-) When there is a boot option `persistent`, the system will look into the connected drives and grab the first casper-rw file or partition that it finds.

Comment: i want to do this with basic file system disk images,  not a usb boot pen drive,  so  i want to do it all command line,

Comment: 1. Do you want a system in an internal drive or in two internal drives, that are similar to a persistent live system? Or something else? 2. I'm fine with command line tools. We can talk about that later on. But first we must understand each other concerning what you want - and I am far from sure about that.

Comment: creating the 2 images  like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/create-file-image-container ,  put data in 1 and "LIKE" the ubuntu persistant storage usb feature i want to combine the 2nd image as the persistant part....

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why you want two containers filled with data and why one of them should be read-only.

- Alternative 1: The operating system is in one of them and the persistent storage of data is in the other
- Alternative 2: There are similar data in both, but the newest data are in the second one, which is mounted read-write. In this case you could run some kind of backup or synchronization between the two drives at certain intervals to update the drive that is usually read-only.

I would solve this problem with a persistent live system installed in an internal drive (or in an SSD connected via a USB adapter or box), and have a backup routine, to backup the content of the file or partition for persistence.

Then it would be straightforward to restore the system to what you intend to store in the 'first container', that you want to mount read-only.

Links:

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[Backup & restore of the whole casper-rw partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_.26_restore_of_the_whole_casper-rw_partition)

Comment: The system does not have USB or SATA ports is not virtual and no i cant add these. and it why i requested logic for "not a usb boot pen drive, must use basic filesystem and commands"  and the reasons why is, i am working with a database and i need to snapshot it somehow. and then i need to save the mutated data. for some checking and a few other ideas i would like to hack up.  i was hoping there was someone there that has modified the casperfs style live usb persistant storage steps to achieve the intended goal without "booting" or using a usb drive

Comment: Must you use the current installed system, or would you be able to install a **persistent live system into the internal drive**? I have even installed such a system into an nvme drive, so it is possible without using any USB drive, but you have to get access to that drive somehow (maybe unplug it and plug it into another computer, with some other drive until you have installed the persistent live system. Then you can plug it back into your special computer.

Comment: An alternative might be to have a modern file system, that allows you to make snapshots, when running (for example btrfs or zfs).